# how to redirect a dynamic URL using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Is there any way to redirect this link :

http://example.com/?page=profile.php&id=100

to

http://example.com/profile.php?id=100

using htaccess ??
by the way I know that I can redirect from

http://example.com/?page=profile.php

to:

http://example.com/profile.php

using 301 redirect

but I am asking about the `id` in the first link I use it with `&` while in the second URL I use it with `?` is there a way to make the redirect taking the id parameter in consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=([^&]+)&id=([^&]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1?id=%2 [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: actually when I add this to the `.htaccess` file and call the old URL I was redirected to somewhere like this `http://example.com/home/account_name/public_html/example.com/profile.php?id=100` so as you can see it is redirected and the `?page` and `?` sign are changed but the problem is in the path . it gives me a new path ?? why does it do that?

Comment: Thank you so much now it is working very good , but I want your recommendation about something , if the URL does not have an id parameter just like this `?page=profile.php` and I want to make it 'profile.php' if I add 301 redirect could that contrast with the code you gave me?